# Using 'starts with' selector on individual class names

Tags: jquery

If I have the following:

```
<div class="apple-monkey"></div>
<div class="apple-horse"></div>
<div class="cow-apple-brick"></div>
```

I can use the following selector to find the first two DIVs:

```
$("div[class^='apple-']")
```

However, if I have this:

```
<div class="some-other-class apple-monkey"></div>
<div class="apple-horse"></div>
<div class="cow-apple-brick"></div>
```

It will only find the second DIV, since the first div's class is returned as a string (I think) and doesn't actually start with 'apple-' but rather 'some-'

One way around that is to not use starts with, but instead contains:

```
$("div[class*='apple-']")
```

The problem with that is it will also select the 3rd DIV in my example.

Question: Via jQuery, what is the proper way to use predicate selectors on individual class names, rather than the entire class attribute as a string? Is it just a matter of grabbing the CLASS, then splitting it into an array and then looping through each individual one with regex? Or is there a more elegant/less verbose solution?

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Classes that start with "apple-" plus classes that contain " apple-"

```
$("div[class^='apple-'],div[class*=' apple-']")
```

Comment: +1. Although I agree with @parrots' suggestion that "apple" should be its own class here, since it obviously overlaps multiple divs yet is a distinct entity. But this does solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm...clever! I hadn't thought of using space in there. Can one use boolean operators in a jquery selector? Ideally, the above would be 'OR' to avoid the (rare and likely avoidable) case where there are more than one class staring with 'apple-'

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if you only want to use the second selector when the first selector returns zero elements, you could do something like this:  `var divs = $("div[class^='apple-']"); if(divs.length == 0) divs = $("div[class*=' apple-']");`

Comment: now that I think about it, your initial solution works just fine. A DIV that had a class like "apple-brick apple-horse" would still be just selected once into the jQuery object.

Comment: use * instead of div if you not bounding class for specific element :)

Answer (score 16):

I'd recommend making "apple" its own class. You should avoid the starts-with/ends-with if you can because being able to select using `div.apple` would be a lot faster. That's the more elegant solution. Don't be afraid to split things out into separate classes if it makes the task simpler/faster.

Comment: How do you figure it would be alot faster?  It still has to scan the entire DOM and evaluate the class attribute.  It would be marginally faster (at best) because it would not have to substring the class attribute.  Negligible.

Comment: http://www.componenthouse.com/article-19 : If you look in the get by class section, using the regular dot syntax is usually a decent bit faster than treating the class as an attribute. Add the substring searching (and the additional work he'll have to do to break out elements with multiple class names) and it'll add up to a decent performance savings.

Comment: I agree. The catch is that we're still heavily supporting IE6 and it doesn't support compound selectors in CSS: .class1.class2.class3 as such, we're relying on using longer class names where 'parameters' are divided by dashes.

Answer (score 13):

While the top answer here is a workaround for the asker's particular case, if you're looking for a solution to actually using 'starts with' on individual class names:

You can use this custom jQuery selector, which I call `:acp()` for "A Class Prefix." Code is at the bottom of this post.

```
var test = $('div:acp("starting_text")');
```

This will select any and all `<div>` elements that have at least one class name beginning with the given string ("starting_text" in this example), regardless of whether that class is at the beginning or elsewhere in the class attribute strings.

```
<div id="1" class="apple orange lemon" />
<div id="2" class="orange applelemon banana" />
<div id="3" class="orange lemon apple" />
<div id="4" class="lemon orangeapple" />
<div id="5" class="lemon orange" />

var startsWithapp = $('div:acp("app")');
```

This will return elements 1, 2, and 3, but **not** 4 or 5.

Here's the declaration for the `:acp` custom selector, which you can put anywhere:

```
$(function(){
    $.expr[":"].acp = function(elem, index, m){
          var regString = '\\b' + m[3];
          var reg = new RegExp(regString, "g");
          return elem.className.match(reg);
    }
});
```

I made this because I do a lot of GreaseMonkey hacking of websites on which I have no backend control, so I often need to find elements with class names that have dynamic suffixes. It's been very useful.

Answer (score 9):

this is for prefix with

`$("div[class^='apple-']")`

this is for starts with so you dont need to have the '-' char in there

`$("div[class|='apple']")`

you can find a bunch of other cool variations of the jQuery selector here
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="apple-monkey"></div>
<div class="apple-horse"></div>
<div class="cow-apple-brick"></div>
```

in this case as question Josh Stodola answer is correct 
Classes that start with "apple-" plus classes that contain " apple-"

```
$("div[class^='apple-'],div[class*=' apple-']")
```

but if element have multiple classes like this

```
<div class="some-class apple-monkey"></div>
<div class="some-class apple-horse"></div>
<div class="some-class cow-apple-brick"></div>
```

then Josh Stodola's solution will do not work
for this have to do some thing like this

```
$('.some-parent-class div').filter(function () {
  return this.className.match(/\bapple-/);// this is for start with
  //return this.className.match(/apple-/g);// this is for contain selector
}).css("color","red");
```

may be it helps some one else thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("div[class]").filter(function() {
    var classNames = this.className.split(/\s+/);
    for (var i=0; i<classNames.length; ++i) {
        if (classNames[i].substr(0, 6) === "apple-") {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})
```