# jQuery. Select all the elements that classname starts with

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have elements with classnames like this:

```
   .ses_0 .ses_1 .ses_2 .ses_3
```

How can I select all the elements and prepend those with some snippet?
Something like this:

```
    var sessions = $('*[class*=ses_]');

    for (var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++)
    {
        sessions [i].prepend("<img src='/Content/img/caticon"+i+".png' />");
    }
```

That doesn't work of course.

**Edit:** Ahhhh... damn It seems that I need to get not only those classes that start with .ses_ but also   `<a>` elements within. How can I do that?

Basically something that works `$(".ses_0 a")` , only I need to get all the classes start with ses_

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
// selects all that start with "ses_"
var sessions = $('[class^="ses_"]');
```

Even though your loop should work, you could also use the

```
sessions.each(function(index){
    this.prepend(... // and so on
});
```

Comment: what if I need to get all the anchors (a tags) within elements which class name starts with ses_?

Comment: Just add an 'a' at the beginning of the selector `$('a[class^="ses_"]');`

Comment: var anchors = $('[class^="ses_"] a');

Comment: My selector should work if you have the anchors inside the element with class starting with "ses_". Just tested it :).  john_doe's will select the anchors with classes staring with "ses_" -- not what you asked for.

Comment: Ba careful if your element has multiple classes, it might not start by the one you're expecting. `<a class="anotherclass ses_1">` will not be found by `$('a[class^="ses_"]')`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2178504/183386

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute starts with selector in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Beware that it's not nearly as fast as using the regular way of selecting elements.