# find element in dom, which has a second classname starting with certain letters with jquery

Tags: jquery, class, selector

I look for all links, which have a second classname, which starts with "_0". This classname works as a path for my internal use.

I tried the following queries with no success:

```
$('a.hint [class^=_0]') // hint is the name for the first class
$('a [class^=_0]')
$('a [class^=_0]')
```

Is there a short handy query to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$('a.hint[class^="_0"]')` (with quotes surrounding the `_0`) as described in the [jquery doc example](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[EDIT] If one of your classes is not **exactly** `hint` then you shouldn't use `a.hint`

`$('a.hint[class^="_0"]')` look for a `a` tag containing the exact class name `hint` **and** one of the classes name begining with `_0`

What you are looking for is more probably: `$('a[class^="_0"]')`

You should show us your HTML code, that would really help!

Comment: @Andreas: indeed, i forgot to remove the space between  `hint` and `[` as Richard pointed out in his answer - i've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a space after the a, also you could probably use the attribute contains selector instead:

```
$('a.hint[class*="_0"]')
```

http://jsbin.com/onazul/2/edit

Comment: that would find these letters in the middle of the classname as well

Comment: Are you going to have those letters in the middle of a class name? Yes, you can check if it starts with 'hint _0'

Answer (score 0):

try this-

`$('a.hint [class^="_0"]')`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that its your second class then you can use `$("a [class*=' _0']")`. Please refer to this link this should help you. [Using 'starts with' selector on individual class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178416/jquery-using-starts-with-selector-on-individual-class-names)