# How can I get element by ClassName with starts with a certain string?

Tags: javascript

I need to get element by ClassName which starts with:

`width-48 height-48 profile_view_img`

The full tag:

```
<div class="width-48 height-48 profile_view_img_9131256"></div>
```

The numbers of this class always changes.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var x = window.document.querySelectorAll("*[class^=\"width-48 height-48 profile_view_img\"]")[0]
```

Comment: And did this not work? What did you get? Can we see your HTML also?

Comment: Why do you want to use such a fragile selector?

Comment: Do you want to select one element that starts with all three classes?

Comment: Can you share some sample, may be create a JSFiddle.

Comment: Your code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/5wvu7b8y/2/

Comment: Please visit this for JQuery way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2178504/3080799

Comment: @Jacques Marais it returns [object HTMLSpanElement] - but how can it return exactly the class name?

Comment: @Andrew So you want to get `className` of the element?

Comment: @Jacques Marais yes

Comment: @Jacques Marais Thank You so much, it worked!

Comment: @Andrew Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var x = window.document.querySelectorAll("*[class^=\"width-48 height-48 profile_view_img\"]")[0]
var className = x.className;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wvu7b8y/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the `querySelector` like this:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".width-48.height-48.profile_view_img");
```

Or just use `getELementsWithClass` which accepts spaces like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("width-48 height-48 profile_view_img");
```

Comment: The OP meant the classes should start with those strings, not be those strings.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

Try:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.width-48.height-48.profile_view_img')[0];
```

This reads as:

> Let **Variable X** be *the first element* in the
>   document which contains the classes `.width-48` AND `.height-48` AND
>   `.profile_view_img`.

Comment: The OP meant the classes should start with those strings, not be those strings.

Comment: What happens if it doesn't find any such elements?

Comment: You're quite right, @JacquesMarais - I missed that.

Answer (score -1):

For the **first** element that has classes with names starting with

`width-48` and `height-48` and `profile_view_img`

you can try with:

```
var x = window.document.querySelectorAll("*[class^='width-48'] *[class^='height-48'] *[class^='profile_view_img']")[0]
```

Comment: This is the descendant selector.