# How to check if substring exists in CSS Class and remove it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

We have several CSS classes with the following pattern below. They all start with either `bg--` or `color--`. How can I check if an element contains the CSS class substring using `jQuery` and if found then remove it?

Examples:

1. `bg--white`
2. `bg--red`
3. `bg--orange`
4. `color--orange`
5. `color--red`
6. `color--purple`

What I tried

```js
$(function() {
  var divEl = $('div');
  if(divEl.hasClass('*=bkg--') {
    divEl.removeClass('*=bkg--'); 
  }
  if(divEl.hasClass('*=color--') {
    divEl.removeClass('*=color--'); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bkg--red color--white">Holisticly build resource sucking methodologies before distributed methodologies. </div>
<div class="bkg--orange color--white">Phosfluorescently integrate revolutionary collaboration and idea-sharing through efficient services.</div>
<div class="bkg--purple color--purple">Credibly maximize impactful e-tailers with resource-leveling convergence. </div>
```

Comment: Are you looking to see if they start with bg-- or color-- or trying to get the value after the --?

Comment: @bhmahler sorry i had to update the question because I forgot to mention the remove part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 'starts with' selector on individual class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178416/using-starts-with-selector-on-individual-class-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the desired `.prop()` *(`"class"` in your case)* and change it on the fly using JS's [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
$("div").prop("class", function( i, cls ) {

  console.log("Before: "+ cls )
  cls = cls.replace(/(^|\s)(bg|color)--\S+/g, '');
  console.log("After: "+ cls )
  
  return cls;
});
```

```css
.bg--white {background: white;}
.bg--red {background: red;}
.bg--orange {background: orange;}
.color--orange {color: orange;}
.color--red {color: red;}
.color--purple {color: purple;}
```

```html
<div class="test bg--red color--white">Holisticly</div>
<div class="foo--bar bg--orange color--white">Phosfluorescently</div>
<div class="bg--purple color--purple">Credibly</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Or simply:

```
$("div").prop("class", function( i, cls ) {
  return cls.replace(/(^|\s)(bg|color)--\S+/g, '');
});
```

Or if you use a JS compiler (like i.e: Babel.js)

```
$("div").prop("class", (i, c) => c.replace(/(^|\s)(bg|color)--\S+/g, ''));
```

---

Additionally, instead of using the *too general* `$("div")` you can instead change your selector to:

```
$("[class^='bg--'], [class*=' bg--'], [class^='color--'], [class*=' color--']")
```

It's a bit long but it does the job perfectly fine.

Comment: i found out that i can use `[class^="bkg--"]` to get what i need, but this worked really well.

Comment: @usernameabc nope. Because `[class^="bkg--"]` will **not work** if your element has another leading class like i.e: `class="test bg-orange"`

Comment: @RokoCbuljan I just tested that and found the same as you mentioned. All the more reason to continue with the approach you provided.

Comment: @usernameabc I expanded on my answer if you want to get rid of the somewhat too iterative `$("div")` selector.