# I want to use jQuery regular expression in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Element ID :

```
<div class="text_title_9a9f19a9 text_title-191 textListLayoutTitle_9a9f19a9">
```

I am want to get this element using below code

```
$("div:regex(class, .text_title_\*.text_title-\*.textListLayoutTitle_\*)");
```

but it's not working

In element id "9a9f19a9" and "191" and "9a9f19a9" are dynamically change the value so that's why I am using `*` instead of that

Comment: Try `$("div[class*="text_title_"]")`

Comment: use `$('div[class^="text_title_"]');` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178416/using-starts-with-selector-on-individual-class-names

Answer (score 1):

You can use the selector `div[class^=text_title]` to select all `div` that has a class starting with `text_title`, this way you don't have to use a regex for it.

```
$("div[class^=text_title]")
```

If you wish to look for multiple classes on the div you can do it like this:

```
$("div[class*=text_title_][class*=text_title-][class*=textListLayoutTitle_]")
```

**Demo**

```js
console.log($("div[class*=text_title_][class*=text_title-][class*=textListLayoutTitle_]").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text_title_9a9f19a9 text_title-191 textListLayoutTitle_9a9f19a9"></div>

<div class="text_title_9a9f19a9 textListLayoutTitle_9a9f19a9"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `filter()` function and use `indexOf` to check containing classess

```js
$(function(){
  $('div').filter(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class');
    if(classes.indexOf('text_title_') != -1 && classes.indexOf('text_title-') != -1 && classes.indexOf('textListLayoutTitle_') != -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }).addClass('valid');
});
```

```css
.valid {
  color: green;
}

div {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text_title_9a9f19a9 text_title-191 textListLayoutTitle_9a9f19a9">Valid</div>
<div class="text_title-191 textListLayoutTitle_9a9f19a9">InValid</div>
<div class="text_title_9a9f19a9 textListLayoutTitle_9a9f19a9">InValid</div>
```