# Replace image title attributes on specific classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to swap out the title attribute on all images on the page that contain the string `slide` in the class name. The image class names vary and are followed by a unique numeric string (ex: `slide-1234`, `slider-4321`) so it's important it just contains the string `slide`. I want to replace it with the WordPress post title. Here is my code so far (doesn't work)

```
<script>
var title = '{{get_the_title()}}';
$('img[class*=slide]').attr('title', title);
</script>
```

Very simple, but unfortunately doesn't work. I used `alert` to debug and was able to print the title, but the selector is the issue.

Here's the HTML

```
<h6 class="text-primary mb-5 mt-5">Session Photos</h6>
<div id="metaslider-id-1572" style="width: 100%;" class="ml-slider-3-15-3 metaslider metaslider-flex metaslider-1572 ml-slider">
    <div id="metaslider_container_1572">
        <div id="metaslider_1572">
            <ul aria-live="polite" class="slides">
                <li style="display: block; width: 100%;" class="slide-1573 ms-image"><img src="https://knowledge.page.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/DSC04292-850x500.jpg" height="500" width="850" alt="" class="slider-1572 slide-1573" title="DSC04292" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging in the console to check what is returned after using `$('img[class*=slide]')` and then if `$('img[class*=slide]').attr('title', 'anything here');` worked or not?

Comment: Or just `console.log($('img[class*=slide]').length)` and see if it's > 0... I would suggest just adding a class "slide" to those images you want to target. Then you could just use `$('.slide')`...

Comment: your code looks correct. just ensure your script comes __after__ your html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your script is running before the DOM is fully loaded. You can either place the script code at the bottom of the *body* tag **OR** try wrapping your code with `$(document).ready(function(){...})`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var title = 'someTitle';
    $('img[class*=slide-]').attr('title', title);
  });
</script>

<h6 class="text-primary mb-5 mt-5">Session Photos</h6>
<div id="metaslider-id-1572" style="width: 100%;" class="ml-slider-3-15-3 metaslider metaslider-flex metaslider-1572 ml-slider">
    <div id="metaslider_container_1572">
        <div id="metaslider_1572">
            <ul aria-live="polite" class="slides">
                <li style="display: block; width: 100%;" class="slide-1573 ms-image"><img src="https://knowledge.page.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/DSC04292-850x500.jpg" height="500" width="850" alt="" class="slider-1572 slide-1573" title="DSC04292" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Comment: Be advised that if you were to use, for example, `class="some-class slider-4321"` the starts with selector will not work. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178416/using-starts-with-selector-on-individual-class-names) for a solution.

Comment: @Mamun thats what I had expected

Comment: @ChrisMcGlade If this is the correct answer, please tick it so that this answer gets marked as the correct answer. Its a good motivation for these people who help as well as gets their efforts recognized.