Making a smarter jQuery code applied to a Wordpress Menu
On my Wordpress menu I tagged a .custom-class-n on each links via the back-office. This gives a menu structure like this :
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item-227" class="custom-class-1 menu-item ..."></li>
  <li id="menu-item-228" class="custom-class-2 menu-item ..."></li>
  ...
  <li id="menu-item-n" class="custom-class-n menu-item ..."></li>
</ul>

For each .custom-class I have another list that mirrors like this :
<div>
  <p class="custom-class-1"></p>
  <p class="custom-class-2"></p>
  ...
  <p class="custom-class-n"></p>
</div>

The end result is : when I hover .custom-class-1 thenp.custom-class-1 reacts.
For now, I managed it through jQuery via this code :
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
$('li.custom-class-1').on("mouseenter", function () {
    $('p.custom-class-1').addClass("hover");
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
    $('p.custom-class-1').removeClass("hover");
    }); });

It works fine, but I have to duplicate it for each instance which is big and not viable for the end user.
How do I make this code? So I don't have to copy-paste it for every .custom-class-n
Note that the .custom-class-n is always first in line in the wordpress structure.

You need to delegate - life gets easier if you use data attributes


$(function() {
  $('li[id^="menu-item"]').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event) {
    $(`p.${this.dataset.target}`).toggleClass("hover", event.type === "mouseenter");
  });
});
p.hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item-227" data-target="custom-class-1" class="menu-item">227</li>
  <li id="menu-item-228" data-target="custom-class-2" class="menu-item">228</li>
  <li id="menu-item-n" data-target="custom-class-n " class="menu-item">n</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <p class="custom-class-1">P 1 </p>
  <p class="custom-class-2">P 2</p>
  <p class="custom-class-n">P n</p>
</div>




Thank you, very hepful. But the end user doesn't have access to the code and can only add a CSS class in the back office. I use a condition that finds the first in line class and apply a function :  var className = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').find(cls => cls.startsWith('custom-class-'));

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48328053/295783
